# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem use case

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use that method this way:

```
public void Method()
{
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() =>
        {
            while(!paused)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() => {...);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem comes cause it throws me a compilation error in the first call.

> error CS1593: Delegate `System.Threading.WaitCallback' does not take`
>   0' arguments

Any idea of how to do it without arguments? , any alternative?

Comment: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => {...);
Callback requires object parameter. Though you don't have to use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just provide a parameter for the lambda expression, and ignore it:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ignored =>
{
    while(!paused)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(alsoIgnored => {...});
    }
});
```

Or use an anonymous method instead:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
{
    while(!paused)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {...});
    }
});
```

If you don't care about parameters for anonymous methods, you don't have to state them.

Answer (score 2):

`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` requires a `System.Threading.WaitCallback` delegate as its parameter. This delegate has one parameter while your lambda expression has no. If you want to ignore the parameter you can use:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
{
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The delegate you pass needs to take one argument. If you want to ignore it, you can just replace the brackets with any variable name.